# Is there a way to advancely search my computer for files made from 2011?

Tags: windows-10, search

Is there a way to look for files (specifically pictures) which their modification date or date of creation is 2011 or older? I Googled it and came up short.

OS: Windows 10

Really appreciate it.

Comment: Related:  [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](//superuser.com/q/531659/150988)

Answer (score 5):

The search built into File Explorer supports this. Try a search string of, for example,

> `kind:=picture datemodified:‎1900-‎01-‎01 .. ‎2011-‎12-‎31`

The spaces around the two dots are not critical, but the two dots are.

For the first date, just use something that's guaranteed to be older than anything you're looking for.

You'll probably want to change the date format to whatever is normal for your machine - use the format that Explorer normally shows for files (usually mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy). I use yyyy-mm-dd because it's unambiguous.

Note that if you type as far as "datemodified:" it will bring up a date picker with a calendar GUI. You can spec a date range by clicking one date, then holding Shift and clicking a second one. But it will be a little tedious to use that for date ranges far in the past. To enter the dates yourself, just keep typing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [GUI method for file searches by modification date](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/explorer/datemodified/) listed by Jamie Hanrahan (I didn't know you could also specify the kind of files until seeing his post), you can also [use PowerShell to perform searches on files by date](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/PowerShell/files_before_after_date.php). E.g., to find all [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image files that were last modified in 2011 or before, i.e., before January 1, 2012, you could use the command below:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\*.png -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt '1/1/2012'}
```

The `-Recurse` parameter instructs [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) to perform a recursive search. If you were only interested in files in the specified directory and not its subdirectories, you could omit `-Recurse`. If you only wanted to search in the current directory, you don't need to specify the directory path. If you wanted to search for both JPG and PNG files, you could use the command below:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\*.[jp][pn]g -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt '1/1/2012'}
```

By putting the letters "j" and "p" within brackets, any file where the first letter of the extension is either "j" or "p" will match. Like wise using "[pn]" matches on either "p" or "n" as the second letter.

Note: If you don't run the command from an PowerShell prompt with administrator privileges on the system you will see "access denied" messages for directories for which you don't have access. You can run PowerShell with administrator privileges on Windows 10 by typing "powershell" in the [Cortana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortana_(software)) "Ask me anything" field, then when you see it listed in the "best match" result, right click on "Windows PowerShell" and choose "Run as administrator". Then provide a user name and password for an account that is in the administrators group for the system.